# What's endpoint url in aws api deployment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, deployment

I want to deploy my API to AWS, there is an Endpoint URL, but I have no idea what's this[image]

Any help please, thank you.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what the endpoint is?

Answer (score 1):

The [HTTP integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/setup-http-integrations.html) will forward any requests to API gateway to your HTTP endpoint which you already must have. For example, you can create some API server of your own on an EC2 instance, and API gateway through HTTP integration will proxy all requests to your instance. In this case, the HTTP endpoint will be your EC2 url.

But if you don't know what is your HTTP endpoint, then probably you don't need to use HTTP integration. Maybe [lambda integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-integrations.html) would be better.